# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Add User",
        id: "new-record-add-button",
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            form.submit({
                url: BasePath+'/main/admin/adduser',
                method: 'POST',
                waitTitle: 'Authenticating',
                waitMsg: 'Please Wait',
                success: function(form, action) {
                win.close()
                     Ext.Msg.show({
                         title:'Success'
                        ,msg:'User added successfully'
                        ,modal:true
                        ,icon:Ext.Msg.INFO
                        ,buttons:Ext.Msg.OK
                });
                },

            failure: function(form, action) {

                console.log(action.response.responseText);
                obj = Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                console.log(obj);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error',obj.errors)
                form.reset();
            }
        })

                //this.up("window").close();
        }

    },
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        handler: function() {
            this.up("window").close();
        }
    }
]
```

I am getting the following error when I reach the failure function in my form:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined
```

This is my php code:

```
public function adduserAction()
{
            $response = new JsonModel();
            //$error = array();
            $errors="";
            if(!ctype_alpha($_POST["first_name"])) {
                $errors.="First Name cannot contain characters and numbers";
            }
            if(!ctype_alpha($_POST["last_name"])) {
                $errors.="Last Name cannot contain characters and numbers";
            }

            if(!filter_var($_POST['email_address'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors.="Email should be of the format john.doe@example.com";
            }
            if(empty($_POST["role"])) {
                $errors.="Role cannot be empty";
            }
            if($errors!="") {
                $response->setVariables(array("success"=>false, "errors"=>$errors));

            }
            else {
                $response->setVariables(array("success"=>true, "errors"=>$errors));

            }
            return $response;
}
```

Comment: Is this a PHP or a JavaScript error? I assume JavaScript…

Comment: The error in the title is a JavaScript error.

Comment: javascript..why the downvote. I have added a tag extjs4. and thats an obvious extjs4 errro

Comment: `action.response.responseText` is used in `failure` handler. From this error I can say that `action.response` is undefined. But why? Replace `console.log(action.response.responseText)` with `console.log(action)` then you will see structure of `action` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`responseText` is an ExtJs thing - it represents the actual text returned from the server (eg, using `echo`) before being decoded.

You should get it in asynchronous callbacks within the `operation` or `request` objects, unless there was a server exception of a sort or if you set `success` to `false`, that's why you don't get it in the failure handler.

To really understand what's going on with it I recommend you have a look at [Connection.js](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/Connection.html#Ext-data-Connection).

Answer (score 0):

if you do a form submit through ExtJs, then on success of the form submission it needs response.responseText to be set as {"sucess":"true"}. if you are submitting the form to some page you have to make sure that you will be returning this object from backend. Or else you have to override the existing onSuccess method.

The second way is something like this,

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.action.Submit,{

    onSuccess: function(response) {
        var form = this.form,
            success = true,
            result = response;
            response.responseText = '{"success": true}';
            form.afterAction(this, success);
        }
    });
```

Place this snippet in your application and see the magic. Cheers. :)